# The font color of hyperlinks on ux meta is hard to read

Tags: feature-request, design, usability

The font color of hyperlinks, especially unvisited hyperlinks, on UX meta (yellow on a white background) is very hard to read. Maybe we could add more contrast?

Comment: You're referring to the unvisited link color I assume?

Comment: Yes, the titles of the questions before you opened them. :visited links are easier to see, but still rather light.

Comment: Agreed, the unvisited link text is a bit bright on white.

Comment: I've updated the question to refer to hyperlinks in specific.

Comment: Basically, [SE should steer clear of yellow](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/choice-of-colours-in-the-new-design-does-not-represent-our-brand).

Comment: @fredley poor yellow, gets no respect. A highly problematic and polarizing color however.

Answer (score 4):

Note: The colour currently used [violates WCAG compliance](http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html) for readability.

[image]

Note also: The `:visited` colour is *just about* compliant, but still not ideal.

Comment: I'm not colorblind, but I have an exceedingly difficult time telling what each color MEANS.  The darker, more readable color is the color of a link that I've already visited, while the paler, more squint-inducing color is one that I have yet to go to.  It confuses me every single time I look at the "Related" list in Meta.